# How to avoid posts from moving to trash based off of a condition?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

**Issue**: How should I go for a conditional "move to trash" action? It means that delete a particular post only when a certain condition is met. Otherwise, prompt user that this can't be done.

**Things I've tried**: I am calling a function on `pre_trash_hook` and checking my condition. But I'm not sure how to stop WordPress from not moving forward with further "move to trash" action. Here's the code for reference.

```php
public function register_pre_trash_handler( $product_post_type, $product_comparator_type_meta_key ) {

    $this->product_post_type = $product_post_type;
    $this->product_comparator_type_meta_key = $product_comparator_type_meta_key;

    add_filter( "pre_trash_post", array( $this, "safe_comparator_trash_cb" ), 10, 2 );
  }

  public function safe_comparator_trash_cb( $should_trash, $post ) {

    $product_posts = get_posts( array(
      "post_type" => $this->product_post_type,
      "meta_key" => $this->product_comparator_type_meta_key,
      "meta_value" => $post->ID
    ) );

    if ( ! empty( $product_posts ) ) { // this is the condition. If products exist, don't move the comparator to trash

      $should_trash = null;
    }
  }
```

FYI, not a big fan of PHP and never used it other than tinkering WordPress themes.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `wp_trash_post` hook.

```
add_action('wp_trash_post', 'prevent_from_trash');
public function prevent_from_trash($post_id) {
  if (! empty( $product_posts )) { // your condition
    wp_redirect(get_home_url() . "/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=" . $custom_post_type);
    die();
  }
}
```

This solution only prevents trashing the post but does not gives any warning, nor notice that it does not want to trash the post.